# searchfunction with JQuery AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql, ajax

So Im designing a searchfunction for the backend of a website and Im doing so with AJAX.

So far if you press the "Members" Button it gets the relevant info from the database and displays the members in a table. So far so good.

Now I added a form above the div in which it displays the table:

```
    <form id="searchmember" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="searchm" placeholder="Look for a Member!"/>
        <input id="search" type="submit" value=">>" name="search"/>
    </form>

    <div id="eachTable">
```

And added a function into my JQuery that reacts when the "search" button gets pressed:

```
$("#search").click(function(){   
  if(ifIssetData == 1){
    var searchm = $('input[name="searchm"]').val();
    $.post('/website/administrator/components/com_backend/searchPerson.php', 'val=' + $(searchm).val());

    $.ajax({
      async:   true,
      dataType: 'json',
      url: '/website/administrator/components/com_backend/searchPerson.php',

      error: function(data2, error2, errorThrown2){
        alert(JSON.stringify(data2));  
        alert(error2);
        alert(errorThrown2); 
      }, 

      success: function(data2,status)
      {
        createTableByJqueryEach2(data2);
      },
    });
```

The createTable function is designed to take the data, put it into a table and display that table in the eachTable Div.

So you see it posts searchm to the php file where the following happends:

```
<?php 
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/website/dbConnection.php');

    $searchtrue = $_POST['val'];

    $query = "SELECT Titel, Vorname, Nachname, Unternehmen, Gruppe FROM mitglieder WHERE Titel LIKE '%$searchtrue%' OR Vorname LIKE '%$searchtrue%' OR Nachname LIKE '%$searchtrue%' OR Unternehmen LIKE '%$searchtrue%' OR Gruppe LIKE '%$searchtrue%'";

    function filterTable($query)  
    {   
        $filter_Result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['connect'], $query);
        return $filter_Result;
    }

    $searchresult = filterTable($query) or die("Tabelle kann nicht angezeigt werden");

    $data2 = mysqli_fetch_all($searchresult);
    echo json_encode($data2);
?>
```

So now that you have the code, the Issue. When I press the "search" button the page just reloads and nothing happens. I assume the PHP File doesnt receive the POST? But why? The html is very simple so Im sure that works. The PHP *should* work but Im not sure since I always had a difficult time getting JQuery and PHP Files to work together.

Anybody know where my issue lies?

edit: I thought Ill just add the function in case the issue lies there

```
  function createTableByJqueryEach2(data2)
  {

  var eTable2="<table><thead><tr><th colspan='5'>Created by for loop</th></tr><tr><th>Titel</th><th>Vorname</th><th>Name</th><th>Unternehmen</th><th>Gruppe</th</tr></thead><tbody>"
  $.each(data2,function(index2, row2){
    // eTable += "<tr>";
    // eTable += "<td>"+(data2)[i]['Titel']+"</td>";
    // eTable += "<td>"+(data2)[i]['Vorname']+"</td>";
    // eTable += "<td>"+(data2)[i]['Name']+"</td>";
    // eTable += "<td>"+(data2)[i]['Unternehmen']+"</td>";
    // eTable += "<td>"+(data2)[i]['Gruppe']+"</td>";
    // eTable += "</tr>";

    eTable2 += "<tr>";
    $.each(row2,function(key2,value2){
      eTable2 += "<td>"+value2+"</td>";
    });
    eTable2 += "</tr>";
  });
  eTable2 +="</tbody></table>";
  $('#eachTable').html(eTable2);
}
```

Comment: any reason why you are making two ajax requests to the same url?

Comment: Im REALLY new to JQuery. Like Friday last week new. So I did the post and didnt know if the PHP File is giving back the Table and copy n pasted from the function that displays the table in the first place. Can I just delete the 2nd time I access the PHP File?

Answer (score 0):

Your form is getting submitted as you have a submit input, and it has no action, so it's refresing.

You can change your form to a div or use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#searchmember').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Also, I created this file and it's working nice:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="searchmember" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="searchm" placeholder="Look for a Member!"/>
        <input id="search" type="submit" value=">>" name="search"/>
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#searchmember').on('submit', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });


        $("#search").click(function(e){
            var ifIssetData= 1;
            if(ifIssetData == 1){
                var searchm = $('input[name="searchm"]').val();        
$.post('/website/administrator/components/com_backend/searchPerson.php', 'val=' + $(searchm).val());
                $.ajax({
                    async:   true,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: '/website/administrator/components/com_backend/searchPerson.php',

                    error: function(data2, error2, errorThrown2){
                        alert(JSON.stringify(data2));
                        alert(error2);
                        alert(errorThrown2);
                    },

                    success: function(data2,status)
                    {
                        createTableByJqueryEach2(data2);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I replaced the form with a div and now have a new problem. See my comment on the answer above. Any idea what that could be?

Comment: I added you code on my answer, I declared your `ifIssetData= 1;` as it wasn't declared

Comment: Nope the console is clean

Comment: Yep copy pasted it and its the same. The Button kinda "stays pressed" and nothing happens. When I press something outside the button the button gets "unpressed"

Comment: I'm pretty sure your error is on your php file.
Leave it this way
```<?php

echo "return";
return; ?>```

Or just put that on it first line

Comment: What part of my php should I replace with <?php echo "return"; return; ? All of it?

Comment: Yes!! Also, you can add your php file to this question so I can help you

Comment: My PHP is in the Post :) The 3rd block of code is the PHP File. 

When I replace all of my PHP with that I get a bunch of errors. 

I think thats not the mistake. Maybe youll find something in my PHP that I dont see